# Timezone issues when scheduling a meeting using microsoft-graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

When I schedule a new meeting using Microsoft Graph Explorer, I get the wrong time.

If I call `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailboxsettings`, I get my Time Zone: `"timeZone": "W. Europe Standard Time"`.

If I then call `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events` with the payload:

```
{
  "subject": "My event W. Europe Standard Time 3",
  "start": {
    "dateTime": "2019-04-02T16:01:03.353Z",
    "timeZone": "W. Europe Standard Time"
  },
  "end": {
    "dateTime": "2019-04-02T16:47:03.353Z",
    "timeZone": "W. Europe Standard Time"
  }
}
```

I get the scheduled meeting in my Outlook as expected, but the time is incorrect. The time I get in Outlook is `18:10` to `18:47`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you put a `Z` at the end of the time, you're saying the time *is* UTC. You need to remove the time zone information from the time in order for it to get treated as a local time:

```
{
  "subject": "My event W. Europe Standard Time 3",
  "start": {
    "dateTime": "2019-04-02T16:01:00",
    "timeZone": "W. Europe Standard Time"
  },
  "end": {
    "dateTime": "2019-04-02T16:47:00",
    "timeZone": "W. Europe Standard Time"
  }
}
```